# Parse 'form-data' from incoming webhook using Google Apps Script

Tags: forms, post, google-apps-script, web-applications, multipartform-data

I have a (mulitlevel?) webhook sending into a Google Script (Access:" Anyone"/"Anyone even anonymous") and trying to pull the info out of it with a `doPost()`. I've used ngrok to capture a sample but can't make it work. I'm trying to extract `event` but getting errors like

> 'TypeError Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined'.

I'm using this as one possible starting point to parse it.

```
  function doPost(e) {
try{
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var event = data.event;
} catch(err){
  var mykey = '*************************************8'
  var dataURL = 'https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/Data_Check_WHook/with/key/'+mykey+'?value1=Error:&value2=error: '+event
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(dataURL); 
}
```

Below a sample of the webhook. Do I need to access 'payload' before reading 'event'?

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="payload"
Content-Type: application/json

{"event":"media.pause","user":true,"owner":true,"Account":********************************Hours_2973","summary":"","viewOffset":1391000,"lastViewedAt":1592403577,"year":2019,"thumb":"/library/metadata/5448/thumb/1572876947","art":"/library/metadata/5448/art/1572876947","originallyAvailableAt":"2019-08-15","addedAt":1560188503,"updatedAt":1572876947,"createdAtAccuracy":"epoch","createdAtTZOffset":"3600"}}
--------------------------55b945c1eb00cab0--
```

Comment: What's a getPost()? Can you complete your script?  Please make a complete function.  [mcve]

Comment: I think JSON.stringify(e) is not the thing to do there.

Comment: Can't make it reproducible as can't include account numbers and keys.

Comment: What does your payload look like?

Comment: Yes I'm thinking that too as it's not getting me the results. What would be the thing to do?

Comment: Or are you using a querystring?

Comment: Payload is what I've posted as 'sample'

Comment: I think that you want to be using `e.postData.contents`  Can you share what `JSON.stringify(e);` looks like.

Comment: If I copy the sample part from '{"event"' then I can parse it as a variable, but when it's arriving as a webhook I get nothing.

Comment: How can I get to see what JSON.stringify(e) is giving? That's why I found the ngrok so I could at least see what was coming in. And I've tried e.postData.contents, still get nothing.

Comment: [request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)

Comment: You can use `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));`  or console.log()

Comment: Yes I've been to that page. The only one I have any success with is e.contentLength which does return a number. And for some reason the Logger doesn't seem to work with this function, get nothing, tho I've used it before with other things ok. That's why I used a write to a spreadsheet via IFTTT to at least try to see what the error is.

Comment: Try going to view/executions. You can see the logger there.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Looked there and get: Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'postData' of undefined
    at doPost(Code:11:33)

Comment: Can you update your code?

Comment: Ok, edited to what I have now. That error was from earlier. Just seen that there is a filter for 'executed as me', but without on I'm now seeing seeing current errors and there are no details, just listed as 'failed'.

Comment: Do I need to do something different because it is 'form-data'? Does the name 'payload' have to be included in the parsing function somehow?

Comment: Check `e.parameters`

Comment: Yes I've tried that, still get nothing. Beginning to think maybe there's a different problem. Perhaps the webhook is ok through ngrok but is failing to send properly to G Scripts, because I've tried every method to read it but failing. I'll go do some troubleshooting. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Switch over to "Standard" Google cloud project(search documentation). And send a payload and see  what error is logged in stackdriver logging.